# odd and even function confuse

Tags: calculus

I am trying out some online maths quiz

I know that

- $f$ is even if and only if $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$
- $f$ is odd if and only if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$

however when it come down to this question

$$f(x)=sec(5x)$$

I substitute in $-x$ in to the equation $f(x)=\sec(5x)$

and I obtain

$$f(-x)=\sec5(-x)  \rightarrow-\sec(5x)$$ therefore i got

$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$ is this consider as odd function?

Comment: Hint: Paranthesize properly: $\sec 5(-x) = \sec(5(-x)) = sec(-5x)=sec(5x)$.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Your edit loses this part `f(-x)=sec5(-x) -> -sec(5x)` of the original, which could well be part of the misunderstanding. Note that the OP was missing parantheses around the argument of `sec`, and it looks like he may have been confusing `sec5(-x)` with some sort of product where the `-` sign could "bubble" to the outside.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  let me put that back.

Comment: Letting y=5x this IS the secant function merely applied to another variable. sec is 1/cos where cos is even (by inspection of the unit circle).

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in your calculation. $$f(-x) = \sec (5(-x)) = \frac 1{\cos (-5x)} = \frac 1{\cos 5x} = \sec 5x = f(x)$$

Hence, your function is an even function, since $f(-x) = f(x)$.

Comment: how did $$\frac 1{\cos (-5x)} = \frac 1{\cos 5x} = \sec 5x = f(x)$$ , i thought it will be $$\frac 1{\cos (-5x)} = -\frac 1{\cos 5x} = -\sec 5x = -f(x)$$

Comment: @XWJ The cosine is an even function. To see this, take the Taylor expansion of $\cos x$, and put $-x$ in place of $x$, the expression does not change.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ and it is known that $\cos(x)$ is an even function.

Note that if $f(x)$ is an even function, then $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is an even function since $$g(-x)=\frac{1}{f(-x)}=\frac{1}{f(x)}=g(x)$$

Hence, secant is an even function.

$$\sec(5(-x))=\sec(-5x)=\sec(5x)$$

Hence $\sec(5x)$ is an even function.

Comment: I thought secant being even was the hardest part of the proof!

Comment: hmmm I see. I might not have answered at the right level then. Is it obvious that cosine is even?

Comment: Yes: You can picture it in your head with the unit circle.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to improve the explanation. btw, try to picture secant is an even function in the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

sec=1/cos . cos is even so it is easily shown that sec is even: if f(x)=f(-x) then 1/f(x)=1/f(-x) by substitution. Obviously if sec(-X)=SEC(x) then by substitution sec(-5x)=sec(5x).